# Android Google maps apk showing gray tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, sha1

I'm trying to develop a Google Maps V2 based application with android studio on my mac computer. It is working fine while debugging. I've created a map and added a lot of markers, polygons and polylines on it. Looks great!
I'm using real device not an emulator. Real device connected to my computer via USB cable.

But, If I created an APK file with Android Studio and copy this APK file to real device, my application showing only gray tiles.

I've made too many searches but I couldn't find any solution.

### Please help.

Problem solved. Thanks to [HAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665431/har)
My mistake was using wrong keystore file. When I use right myapp.jks file problem solved.

Comment: Make sure you add your apk SHA1 to the google console list of allowed applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you obtained and entered in the api console is for debugging purposes. You have to obtain sha1 key for the apk file from the Keystore file which you are using to digitally sign the apk

Procedure for obtaining SHA1 key for release mode

1) Go to the location where you have your 'keystore' file which you are using for digitally signing your application.

2) Open command window in that location. This can be done by 'shift+rightClick' and selecting the option 'Open Command Window here'

3) Use the following Command

```
keytool –v –list –keystore <name> -alias <aliasname>
```

where name- your keystore filename
      , aliasname - the alias name for the app

4) Then enter your keystore password

5) you will then get your sha1 keys along with other information. Use the key in the api console.

Comment: I entered this command : keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore and used what I saw. how can I obtain SHA1 key?

Comment: when I entered keytool command I received an error message :    keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias myAlias does not exist.

Comment: you have to enter the correct alias name you have been using for the app .... if you haven't created an alias you have to do it first

Comment: You are my hero! your answer lightened my way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Keytool binary or exe to generate a private keystore. Instructions here. You can then sign your app using this keystore. Keytool gets installed when you install Java.

Test sign apk on your real device